# Edit Polymorphic URL returning pluralized url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use `edit_polymorpic_url(product)` within rails it returns a pluralized version of the resource instead of singular.

For eg.
`edit_polymorpic_url(product)` returns `edit_products_url`  when it should be `edit_product_url`

Anyone know the workaround for this ? Thanks

Comment: Why the url should be in singular? The convention is pluralized names for resources. Could you please explain a little more about what you're doing.

Comment: I dont believe so ? doing `rake routes` will return `edit_product` path.
The idea is simple.. to pass different resources to `edit_polymorphic_url` to retrieve the path instead of doing `edit_product_path(product)`, `edit_something_path(something)`

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Any success? Have this problem now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using polymorphic_path(product, action: :edit)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because of I was passing empty (new) variable when rendering collection.

I added `if my_model.persisted?` before using `polymorphic_path` and it worked.